# moving IconButton on Container flutter

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, android-studio, dart

i have some trouble when i want to moving iconbutton on my profile picture
i just want to move it on right bottom of picture using stack heres some pic that i have try [i want to move the image button on green circle that i put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge2jN.jpg)
and this is my writted code

```
 Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: defaultSize),
                          height: defaultSize * 15,
                          width: defaultSize * 15,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.white, width: defaultSize * 0.5),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.1FbFcWycnyeemiMMsoIJ7gHaF7?w=182&h=145&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7'),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Positioned(
                              right: 0,
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: Container(
                                child: IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.image)),
                              )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Text("Nama Kamu Siapa ")
                  ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error : your Positioned Widget is the child of the Container.

You have to make it a child of the stack :

```
Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.1FbFcWycnyeemiMMsoIJ7gHaF7?w=182&h=145&c=7&r=0&o=5&dpr=1.25&pid=1.7'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                              right: 0,
                              bottom: 0,
                              child: Icon(Icons.image)),
                        ],
                      )
```